# What client-side database should I use with IBM Worklight?

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I am new to working with Worklight, and I'm trying to find out what database I can use on the client-side.

Based on my research, I seem to have two options, the [PhoneGap storage API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) or Worklight's in-built [JSONStore](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v5r0m5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_class_wl_jsonstore.html). They both seem to do pretty much the same thing. What differences are there between the two, and which should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not one set answer for what you're asking.

---

You can take a look [at this feature comparison table](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/r_jsonstore_features.html).

Based on the above table I would go with JSONStore, but should be noted that JSONStore supports only Android and iOS. You can also go the Cordova path or the fully native path and use the native database features each platform offers.

However, there are a couple of questions you need to ask yourself:

1. "Which platforms am I going to support in my application?" and
2. "What exactly do I want to accomplish with a client-side database?"

Based on the above questions and the feature comparison table, you should be able to reach a conclusion, whether to use JSONStore, an alternative, Cordova or the native path... or custom database for each. Whatever you will pick will have a varying degree of coding work to do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wonder why I got voted down. I am pretty new to using StackOverflow, and it isn't always clear what kind of questions I can ask. :(

Comment: Because your question is off-topic to what is expected to be asked in StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - but that's "okay", you've got an answer anyway. ;)